# 'lsblk' is not displaying the GPT partition label after formatting the disk

Tags: debian, partition, gpt, lsblk

My `lsblk` is not showing gpt partition label for one disk partition, which was freshly formatted with

`mkfs.ext4 -v -L MyLabel mydev`

- somehow the partition was not labeled properly afterwards. I didn't notice it until my mount-by-label operation failed.
- I tried to reset the partition label with `e2label`, mount-by-label worked after that, but `lsblk` is still not showing the gpt partition label.
- showing gpt partition label with `blkid` works.

So how can I have `lsblk` showing gpt partition label properly?

```bash
# As root,
# Here is the partition with working label
% blkid -s LABEL -o value /dev/sda9
os2

% lsblk -o NAME,LABEL /dev/sda9
NAME LABEL
sda9 os2

# Here is the partition without working label

% blkid -s LABEL -o value /dev/sda9
os2

% lsblk -o NAME,LABEL /dev/sda8
NAME LABEL
sda8 

$ apt-cache policy util-linux
util-linux:
  Installed: 2.36.1-8+deb11u1
  Candidate: 2.36.1-8+deb11u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: `e2label` sets the `filesystem label`, which isn't the same as `the gpt partition label`

Comment: also, after changing the  filesystem label, it doesn't necessarily appear in `lsblk` output. You could reboot, or just run fdisk/gdisk on the device and write (without making any changes of course) - oh and if you do want the gpt partition label, use gdisk `c` option - and include `PARTLABEL` for the `lsblk -o` option

Comment: Yes, problem gone after reboot, which what I'll be doing next time, rather than trying to fix it before rebooting. thx!

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint about using `PARTLABEL` instead of `LABEL` @JaromandaX !